# Waiting for both keyword and timer events with OCamlSDL (SDL2)

Tags: timer, event-handling, ocaml, keyboard-events, sdl-2

I need to be able to wait for two types of events in the app using OCamlSDL:

1. User key presses
2. Timer events with fixed-time interval

I can see in the tutorial how to wait for events in a loop. My idea was to set up a timer using `SDL_AddTimer` and feed via it custom `USER` events which will be processed in the same loop as the keyboard events. However I do not see OCAML binding for `SDL_AddTimer` SDL function. How can I implement something like this?

Comment: If you can find a way to integrate lwt, there is Lwt_engine.on_timer, although I'm not sure how that would work with SDL.

Comment: I guess you'll have to do it yourself from the functions in `Sdltimer` and `Sdlevent.add`.

Comment: I do not see suitable functions in Sdltimer module: http://ocamlsdl.sourceforge.net/doc/html/Sdltimer.html

Comment: LWT provides cooperative threads and since SDL does not use them they would probably not work here. Another option I am considering is creating a POSIX thread (using Thread module) in OCaml and feed timer events via `Sdlevent.add` from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I found involves running separate POSIX thread which uses `Sldevent.add` to send user-defined events which are then processed in the main event processing loop with keyboard events. Here is a code except which starts the thread:

```
...
and timer_cb () = Sdlevent.add [USER 0]  in
let timer_thread = Thread.create timer_loop (timer_flag, timer_cb) in
loop state; (* runs main program logic *)
timer_flag := true;
Thread.join timer_thread
```

Timer function (executed in separate thread):

```
let rec timer_loop (flag, callback) =
  if !flag then
    Thread.exit
  else
    (Thread.delay 0.5;
     callback ();
     (timer_loop (flag, callback)))
```

Event handling loop except:

```
let rec loop state =
   match wait_event () with
   | KEYDOWN {keysym=KEY_LEFT} ->
      (* process left arrow key press here *)
      loop state
   | USER 0 ->
     (* Process ticks here *)
     loop state
   | KEYDOWN {keysym=KEY_ESCAPE} ->
     (* ESC to exit the app *)
     ()
   | _ ->
     loop state
```